# How to handle concurrent updates in Node

Tags: node.js, database, typeorm

Consider the following scenario on a REST API:

1. User 1 retrieves resource A
2. User 2 retrieves resource A
3. User 1 updates resource A
4. User 2 updates resource A

When User 2 tries to update the resource (4) it should get an error, because that resource was updated by another user (3) after he retrieved it (2). So he should retrieve the resource again to get the updated version and the change it.

On C# with EF Core I use a RowVersion, configuring it like this

```
public class SampleContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }
    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
         modelBuilder.Entity<Author>()
            .Property(a => a.RowVersion).IsRowVersion();
    } 
}
```

On the controller I add an E-Tag header when the user gets a resource

```
Response.Headers.Add(HeaderNames.ETag, entity.RowVersion);
```

When the user tries to update the resource he should send a If-Match header and I check it on the controller

```
Request.Headers.ContainsKey(HeaderNames.IfMatch)
```

If it exists I add to the entity and pass the entity to the respository

```
entity.RowVersion = Request.Headers["If-Match"].First()
```

EF Core adds RowVersion to UPDATE/DELETE queries and if the return 0 rows a DbUpdateConcurrencyException is thrown.

I'm trying to replicate this in Node using TypeORM but I can't find a configuration similar to `.IsRowVersion()` that adds the RowVersion to UPDATE/DELETE queries. Is it possible? If not, is there any other ORM the allows that?

EDIT

I found that TypeORM has @VersionColumn and @UpdateDateColumn decorators, but the fields aren't used in the where clause. Here is the query log of an update

```
UPDATE "users" SET "avatar" = $2, "version" = "version" + 1, "updated_at" = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE "id" IN ($1) RETURNING "updated_at", "version"
```